# Ionic 3 IOS application crash when click on paypal

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, paypal, ionic3, xcode8

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oO0J.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qK4N.png)

[This is the error I am getting on clicking paypal button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lhiq.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtb8I.png)

this app is working fine on Android. But crashing on IOS. Build by IONIC 3. How to solve this issue ? 
The rent button will redirect to the PayPal. Using PayPal Sandbox account.
please help. thanks

2018-05-21 13:04:03.754557+0530 thegrand[665:8151] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/krishanu_mukherjee/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/67065A2C-5E45-47EB-AAD8-5F2E8D5149F4/data/Containers/Data/Application/13D49686-3CB1-4CC3-9967-772BBC693FFA/Library/Cookies/io.ionic.starter.binarycookies
2018-05-21 13:04:04.026035+0530 thegrand[665:8151] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.3 is starting.
2018-05-21 13:04:04.028647+0530 thegrand[665:8151] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2018-05-21 13:04:04.118347+0530 thegrand[665:8151] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2018-05-21 13:04:04.468109+0530 thegrand[665:8151] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2018-05-21 13:04:04.468371+0530 thegrand[665:8151] Using Ionic WKWebView
2018-05-21 13:04:04.470572+0530 thegrand[665:8151] [CDVTimer][console] 0.168085ms
2018-05-21 13:04:04.470968+0530 thegrand[665:8151] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.163078ms
2018-05-21 13:04:04.474148+0530 thegrand[665:8151] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 3.002048ms
2018-05-21 13:04:04.474516+0530 thegrand[665:8151] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.118971ms
2018-05-21 13:04:04.474793+0530 thegrand[665:8151] [CDVTimer][paypalmobile] 0.108004ms
2018-05-21 13:04:04.475352+0530 thegrand[665:8151] CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2018-05-21 13:04:04.476834+0530 thegrand[665:8151] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 1.547933ms
2018-05-21 13:04:04.533597+0530 thegrand[665:8151] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 56.516051ms
2018-05-21 13:04:04.533796+0530 thegrand[665:8151] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 63.489914ms
2018-05-21 13:04:12.591638+0530 thegrand[665:8151] Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
2018-05-21 13:04:12.592087+0530 thegrand[665:8151] deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
2018-05-21 13:04:12.592766+0530 thegrand[665:8151] Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded
2018-05-21 13:04:12.593073+0530 thegrand[665:8151] Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 4048 ms
2018-05-21 13:04:12.896733+0530 thegrand[665:8151] WARN: Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but the StatusBar plugin is not installed.
2018-05-21 13:04:12.897143+0530 thegrand[665:8151] WARN: Install the StatusBar  plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar'
2018-05-21 13:04:13.135458+0530 thegrand[665:8151] CDVWKWebViewEngine: handleStopScroll
2018-05-21 13:04:13.172548+0530 thegrand[665:8151] WARN: Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
2018-05-21 13:04:13.407415+0530 thegrand[665:8151] ERROR: Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
2018-05-21 13:04:20.262243+0530 thegrand[665:8151] CDVWKWebViewEngine: handleStopScroll
2018-05-21 13:04:23.648832+0530 thegrand[665:8151] CDVWKWebViewEngine: handleStopScroll
2018-05-21 13:04:27.249545+0530 thegrand[665:8151] CDVWKWebViewEngine: handleStopScroll
2018-05-21 13:04:30.888592+0530 thegrand[665:8151] CDVWKWebViewEngine: handleStopScroll
2018-05-21 13:04:32.490485+0530 thegrand[665:8151] 1 0
2018-05-21 13:04:32.856165+0530 thegrand[665:8923] A location manager (0x7fbb58f11990) was created on a dispatch queue executing on a thread other than the main thread.  It is the developer's responsibility to ensure that there is a run loop running on the thread on which the location manager object is allocated.  In particular, creating location managers in arbitrary dispatch queues (not attached to the main queue) is not supported and will result in callbacks not being received.
2018-05-21 13:04:32.971875+0530 thegrand[665:8924] -[**NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000c5
2018-05-21 13:04:32.978500+0530 thegrand[665:8924] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000c5'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108eb71e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010851e031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108f38784 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108e39898 ___forwarding_** + 1432
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108e39278 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001042cba3c -[NSScanner(NSDecimalNumberScanning) scanDecimal:] + 303
    6   Foundation                          0x0000000104355f41 -[NSDecimalNumberPlaceholder initWithString:locale:] + 127
    7   Foundation                          0x00000001043561de +[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:] + 46
    8   thegrand                            0x0000000102fb0535 __51-[PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin renderSinglePaymentUI:]_block_invoke + 1013
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a721807 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a722848 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a727675 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1451
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a72e3c8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 664
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a72e0d2 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ac4c1ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ac4bc4d start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Please refine your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using ionic native paypal plugin you will find the line

```
this.payPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', new PayPalConfiguration({
    // Only needed if you get an "Internal Service Error" after PayPal login!
    //payPalShippingAddressOption: 2 // PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal
})).then(() => {
    let payment = new PayPalPayment('3.33', 'USD', 'Description', 'sale');
    this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then(() => {
```

The price will be integer like -> 3.33 not string '3.33' 
in case of android it will work fine but on ios it will crash the app

Comment: Thanks, it worked. just I had to convert the value to string, and the app  stopped crashing